# Discord.js error installing the @ discordjs / opus module for playing mp3 audio

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to play mp3 file.
When I use this code to run mp3 in Discord bot:

```
channel.join().then((connection) => {
connection.play('audio.mp3');
```

I'm getting an error.Error is as follows:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\prism-media\src\util\loader.js:12
  throw new Error(errorLog.join('\n'));
        ^

Error: Error: Cannot find module '@discordjs/opus'
...
```

I understand that I need to install the @ discordjs / opus module, but,
i'm trying to install the @discordjs/opus package, but during the install process I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu>npm i @discordjs/opus
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.3.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@16.0.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.5.0/opus-v0.5.0-node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.5.0/opus-v0.5.0-node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @discordjs/opus@0.5.0 and node@16.0.0 (node-v93 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/discordjs/opus/releases/download/v0.5.0/opus-v0.5.0-node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.0.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.0.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.4 found at "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.9.31205.134) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! (node:2764) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bots\\imamhatipoglu\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.0.0\\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\16.0.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\16.0.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bots\\imamhatipoglu\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bots\\imamhatipoglu\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\16.0.0\common.gypi not found (cwd: C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bots\\imamhatipoglu\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\\opus.node" "--module_name=opus" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bots\\imamhatipoglu\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\opus\\prebuild\\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown\opus.node --module_name=opus --module_path=C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus\prebuild\node-v93-napi-v3-win32-x64-unknown-unknown --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:85:20)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:365:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\bots\\imamhatipoglu\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\bots\imamhatipoglu\node_modules\@discordjs\opus
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.0.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.3.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-30T22_48_11_083Z-debug.log
```

I tried to open cmd as an administrator, but the situation is the same.

My node version: v16

Comment: You can try to ask that in github https://github.com/discordjs/opus/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a Windows user, you must have the build-tools first installed.

As it is written in the v12 [discord guide](https://v12.discordjs.guide/voice/#installing-dependencies), run this command to get them: `npm install --global --production --vs2015 --add-python-to-path windows-build-tools`

MrNossiom